# Scaling vectors by their norm in VectorPlot3D

Tags: plotting, vector-calculus

I'm trying to generate a 3D vector plot in which the length of the vector is really it's norm. This is my code:

```
Ef[x_, y_, z_, Q_, a_] := {(
  x ((5 a^2 Q (x^2 + y^2)^(3/2))/(
     32 \[Pi] (x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^(7/2)) - (a^2 Q Sqrt[x^2 + y^2])/(
     16 \[Pi] (x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^(5/2)) + (Q Sqrt[x^2 + y^2])/(
     4 \[Pi] (x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^(3/2))))/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], (
  y ((5 a^2 Q (x^2 + y^2)^(3/2))/(
     32 \[Pi] (x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^(7/2)) - (a^2 Q Sqrt[x^2 + y^2])/(
     16 \[Pi] (x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^(5/2)) + (Q Sqrt[x^2 + y^2])/(
     4 \[Pi] (x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^(3/2))))/Sqrt[
  x^2 + y^2], (5 a^2 Q (x^2 + y^2) z)/(
   32 \[Pi] (x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^(7/2)) + (Q z)/(
   4 \[Pi] (x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^(3/2))}
Manipulate[
 Show[VectorPlot3D[
   Ef[x, y, z, Carga, Radio], {x, -15, 15}, {y, -15, 15}, {z, 0, 10}, 
   VectorScaling -> "Linear", VectorMarkers -> "Segment", 
   PlotLegends -> Automatic], 
  Graphics3D[Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0.01}}, Radio]]], {Carga, 1, 
  30}, {Radio, 0.1, 15}]
```

I tried using

```
VectorSizes -> {Efmin,Emax}
```

Where Efmax and Efmin are just the extreme values of the norm of the field for my plot, but it didn't work out since the scaling was not affected.

Comment: Use: `VectorSizes -> {0, 1}`

Comment: That does help in showing more dynamics, but it's not an absolute scaling. Thanks anyway, it is helpful.